In Jenkins, "RUN npm install" command in dockerfile run forever
This is my dockerfile. When i run this in local or VPS, it run completely fine.
FROM node:21.1.0

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install
RUN npm run build 
RUN rm -fr node_modules

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"] 

But problem occur, when i run it with Jenkins in "build" stage. "RUN npm install" run forever, approximately 8 hours it still run "RUN npm install".
"RUN npm install"
This is my Jenkinsfile
Jenkinsfile
I tried downgrade version of node in Dockerfile, But still not working.
I took me whole week, and can't deal with it. Can you help me about this problem?. Thanks for reading, and I'm so sorry for my bad english :<.

It seems like network issue can exec into the container and try ping -c 3 google.com. You may need to install net tools for that. Also try to add the registry in docker container manually and check                              npm config get registry
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/

Huge thanks for your help. I found out that the problem is my VPS just only have 1gb RAM. so i have to move 4gb from storage for processing
